# Looking up strings by an index

Tags: pgfplots, for-loop

I'm using  `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,1,2} {...}` and would like to somehow dispatch on `#1` to get one of three strings:

- `$s_A$` if `#1 == 0`
- `$s_B$` if `#1 == 1`
- `$s_C$` if `#1 == 2`

Is there an easy way to do this? I've tried using xstring's `\StrMid` but it bombs and complains about `let` doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution based on LaTeX3. Not sure if it works with `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` in your code though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\intcase}[1]{
  \int_case:nn {#1} {
    {1} {$s\c_math_subscript_token A$}
    {2} {$s\c_math_subscript_token B$}
    {3} {$s\c_math_subscript_token C$}
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\intcase{1}\intcase{2}\intcase{3}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\newcounter{tmpcnt}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,1,2}{%
  \setcounter{tmpcnt}{\numexpr1+#1}$s_{\Alph{tmpcnt}}$}
\end{document}
```

[image]